# How can i Access the roomID which is in App.js and i want to use it in Router.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

> [There is code on left side and file structure in right side[There is code on left side and file structure in right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZts1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiz6f.png)

I tried to fetch the roomID with props, But somehow It is not working i don't know if i did it wrong or not.

Comment: Add your code here, rather then adding multiple images to open and check

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. You want to pass roomID to route in order to retrieve data from some api? meaning you navigate to route /room/roomID to make that call?